# Error: Cannot find symbol Methods

Tags: java, methods

I have created a main class called `ArrayProgram` and another class called `Calculator1`.

The codings are :

```
class ArrayProgram {

    public static void main(String[] shiva) {
        int result[] = Calculator1.generateRandomChar;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

class Calculator1 {

    public static char generateRandomChar() {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 52);
        char base = (rand < 26) ? 'A' : 'a';
        return (char) (base + rand % 26);
    }
}
```

After compiling and later running I get the following error.

```
ArrayProgram.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol : variable generateRandomChar
location : class Calculator1
int result[]=Calculator1.generateRandomChar;
```

**Where did I go wrong..?**

Comment: `Calculator1.generateRandomChar()`. The `.()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`generateRandomChar` is a method so requires brackets `()` . Change this

```
 int result[]= Calculator1.generateRandomChar;
```

to

```
 int result[]= Calculator1.generateRandomChar();
```